# Spring MVC test passing when application is failing

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, junit

Trying to teach myself from the 4th ed. of Spring In Action. I'm building a web app using the book examples as a guide, and working through Chap 5. I have two controllers and two corresponding tests using Spring MVC. BOTH TESTS ARE PASSING, but when I run the application on the server (Tomcat 7.0), it's giving an UnsatisfiedDependencyException based on the ClinicalNoteRepository interface. Why are these tests - specifically the ClinicalNoteControllerTest - passing when the application can't find the ClinicalNoteRepository?

Here are excerpts from the Console output (character limitations won't let me post the whole thing):

> Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
>       WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Practice Wellness' did not find a matching property.
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>       INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>       INFO: Server built:          Nov 3 2014 08:39:16 UTC
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>       INFO: Server number:         7.0.57.0
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>       INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>       INFO: OS Version:            6.1
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>       INFO: Architecture:          amd64
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>       INFO: JAVA_HOME:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>       INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_71-b14
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>       INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>       INFO: CATALINA_BASE:          C:\Users\kyle\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>       INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Apache-Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>       INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\kyle\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>       INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Apache-Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>       INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\kyle\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>       INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Apache-Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\endorsed
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>       INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
>       INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass 2011\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass 2011\;;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11\Driver;;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\syswow64;C:\Program  Files\Broadcom\WHL\SysWow64\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\SysWow64\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Services\IPT\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files\Gradle\Gradle-2.0\gradle-2.2.1\bin;.
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>       INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>       INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>       INFO: Initialization processed in 992 ms
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
>       INFO: Starting service Catalina
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
>       INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>       INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.kwalker.practicewellness.config.WellnessWebAppInitializer@2b1ecc13]
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>       INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>       INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
>       INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Jan 12 05:30:26 MST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
>       INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext -  Registering annotated classes: [class com.kwalker.practicewellness.config.RootConfig]
>       INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
>       WARN : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clinicalNoteController' defined in file  [C:\Users\kyle\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\Practice  Wellness\WEB-INF\classes\com\kwalker\practicewellness\web\ClinicalNoteController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.kwalker.practicewellness.data.ClinicalNoteRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.kwalker.practicewellness.data.ClinicalNoteRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kwalker.practicewellness.data.ClinicalNoteRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
>       ...
>   continued...
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kwalker.practicewellness.data.ClinicalNoteRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
>       ...
>   continued...
>       ... 24 more
>       ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clinicalNoteController' defined in file [C:\Users\kyle\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\Practice Wellness\WEB-INF\classes\com\kwalker\practicewellness\web\ClinicalNoteController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.kwalker.practicewellness.data.ClinicalNoteRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.kwalker.practicewellness.data.ClinicalNoteRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kwalker.practicewellness.data.ClinicalNoteRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1034)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kwalker.practicewellness.data.ClinicalNoteRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>       ... 24 more
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>       SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clinicalNoteController' defined in file  [C:\Users\kyle\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\Practice  Wellness\WEB-INF\classes\com\kwalker\practicewellness\web\ClinicalNoteController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.kwalker.practicewellness.data.ClinicalNoteRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type  [com.kwalker.practicewellness.data.ClinicalNoteRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kwalker.practicewellness.data.ClinicalNoteRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1034)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kwalker.practicewellness.data.ClinicalNoteRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
>       at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionExcepti on(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>       ... 24 more
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
>       SEVERE: Error listenerStart
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
>       SEVERE: Context [/practicewellness] startup failed due to previous errors
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>       INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
>       INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
>       INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
>       Jan 12, 2015 5:30:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>       INFO: Server startup in 3494 ms

ClinicalNoteControllerTest:

```
package com.kwalker.practicewellness;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItems;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.model;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.view;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView;

import com.kwalker.practicewellness.data.ClinicalNoteRepository;
import com.kwalker.practicewellness.domain.ClinicalNote;
import com.kwalker.practicewellness.web.ClinicalNoteController;

public class ClinicalNoteControllerTest {

@Test
public void shouldShowRecentClinicalNotes() throws Exception {
    List<ClinicalNote> expectedClinicalNotes = createClinicalNoteList(20);
    ClinicalNoteRepository mockNoteRepository = mock(ClinicalNoteRepository.class);
    when(mockNoteRepository.findClinicalNotes(Long.MAX_VALUE, 20)).thenReturn(expectedClinicalNotes);

    ClinicalNoteController noteController = new ClinicalNoteController(mockNoteRepository);
    MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(noteController).setSingleView(
            new InternalResourceView("/WEB-INF/views/clinicalNotes.jsp")).build();

    mockMvc.perform(get("/clinical-notes"))
        .andExpect(view().name("clinical-notes"))
        .andExpect(model().attributeExists("clinicalNoteList"))
        .andExpect(model().attribute("clinicalNoteList", hasItems(expectedClinicalNotes.toArray())));
}

@Test
public void shouldShowPagedClinicalNotes() throws Exception {
    List<ClinicalNote> expectedClinicalNotes = createClinicalNoteList(50);
    ClinicalNoteRepository mockRepository = mock(ClinicalNoteRepository.class);
    when(mockRepository.findClinicalNotes(238900, 50)).thenReturn(expectedClinicalNotes);

    ClinicalNoteController noteController = new ClinicalNoteController(mockRepository);
    MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(noteController).setSingleView(
            new InternalResourceView("/WEB-INF/views/clinical-notes.jsp")).build();

    mockMvc.perform(get("/clinical-notes?max=238900&count=50"))
        .andExpect(view().name("clinical-notes"))
        .andExpect(model().attributeExists("clinicalNoteList"))
        .andExpect(model().attribute("clinicalNoteList", hasItems(expectedClinicalNotes.toArray())));
}

private List<ClinicalNote> createClinicalNoteList(int count) {
    List<ClinicalNote> clinicalNotes = new ArrayList<ClinicalNote>();
    for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
        clinicalNotes.add(new ClinicalNote("Note " + i, new Date()));
    }
    return clinicalNotes;
}

}
```

ClinicalNoteController class:

```
package com.kwalker.practicewellness.web;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.kwalker.practicewellness.data.ClinicalNoteRepository;
import com.kwalker.practicewellness.domain.ClinicalNote;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/clinical-notes")
public class ClinicalNoteController {

private static final String MAX_LONG_AS_STRING = "9223372036854775807";
private ClinicalNoteRepository noteRepository;

@Autowired
public ClinicalNoteController(ClinicalNoteRepository noteRepository) {
    this.noteRepository = noteRepository;
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<ClinicalNote> clinicalNotes(
        @RequestParam(value="max", defaultValue=MAX_LONG_AS_STRING) long max,
        @RequestParam(value="count", defaultValue="20") int count) {
    return noteRepository.findClinicalNotes(max, count);
}

}
```

Here is the ClinicalNoteRepository interface:

```
package com.kwalker.practicewellness.data;

import java.util.List;

import com.kwalker.practicewellness.domain.ClinicalNote;

public interface ClinicalNoteRepository {
    List<ClinicalNote> findClinicalNotes(long maximumId, int count);
}
```

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.kwalker</groupId>
<artifactId>practicewellness</artifactId>
<name>Practice Wellness</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.1.4.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Misc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                      <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Your test doesn't do anything with the `ApplicationContext` it is a plain unit test, mocking the dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen from these two lines of code:

```
ClinicalNoteRepository mockNoteRepository = mock(ClinicalNoteRepository.class);
ClinicalNoteController noteController = new ClinicalNoteController(mockNoteRepository);
```

... your tests are unit tests which are creating mock repository instances themselves and constructing the controller using those mock objects.

When running on the server, the Spring configuration is used for determining what beans need to be managed by the framework. Therefore, in your case, there would presumably be a problem with your configuration.

In the code you have provided, `ClinicalNoteRepository` is just an interface. There must be an implementation of an interface which can be used to as the Spring Bean. You haven't shown us such an implementation, so it may just be that you haven't written one. The exception to this rule is if you are using Spring Data, which provides its own implementations. However, in that case, your interface would need to be extending `JpaRepository` or one of the other Spring Data repository interfaces.

Note that you can write tests which will cause the Spring context to be loaded (thereby testing your configuration). To do this, you would need the following annotations adding to your test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyAppConfiguration.class)
```

... assuming that you are using Spring Boot. Or something such as

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyConfiguration.class }, 
                   loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
```

... if you have a more traditional Spring application, in which case you would point it at one or more Java `@Configuration` classes (as above) or a list of XML configuration files.

Comment: This makes sense. In the examples I'm following in the book, the author only provides an interface for the repository without providing any implementation, but he still provides the tests. I found this confusing, and even more so when the tests actually passed while the application is hardly constructed. Thanks for your explanation.